# How to handle button clicks in triggers in update panel VB.Net (But it is working in IE browser)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

When I run my Application in Google Chrome browser, asp.net button clicks are not working after using update panel in my Application, even i mentioned click events inside the Trigger also it is not working.(But it is working in IE browser).

Comment: Check for any javascript error

Comment: share code and js error if occur